# A question regarding finite group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider $k^{*}$ multiplicative subgroup with trivial $G$-module structure. Then I want to prove that $H^{2}(G,k^{*})$  is finite.

Kindly explain in detail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not true in general; for example, the right hand side depends on m and the left hand side doesn't

Comment: I expect $m = |G|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I totally forgot to add that and have edited it as required.

Comment: @hunter Certainly. I have edited the question.

Comment: Try using the [Universal Coefficient Theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dual_universal_coefficient_theorem_for_group_cohomology)

Comment: @DerekHolt while I hate being spoonfed, I am at loss with this problem. Can you please write down the solution in short?

Comment: I can't do that, because I don't think the statement is true in general. When $G$ is cyclic of order $2$ and $k={\mathbb C}$, $H^2(G,k^*)$ is trivial, but $H^2(G,\mu_2)$ has order $2$. Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @DerekHolt I have edited the question to its original form to avoid further confusion. It was asked around 1-2 months back in one of the seminars of the Hom Algebra course that I am taking.  I vaguely remember the discussion. So, I posted by rephrasing the problem to show my effort, which unfortunately has caused the mishap.

Comment: @solgaleo -- you should edit your question to reprovide context, but leave the statement of the problem unchanged. After all, your idea to look at the long exact sequence given by the short exact sequence $0 \to \mu_{|G|} \to k^* \to k^* \to 0$ is a good one, and I suspect you'll get fewer close votes if you reintroduce those ideas into the body of your question ^_^

Comment: To answer the question sensibly we need more context. How much do you know about the theory of Schur Multipliers, projective representations, etc. This result follows easily from the Universal Coefficient Theorem (for a $G$-module $M$ with trivial action $H^2(G,M) \cong {\rm Hom}(H_2(G,{\mathbb Z}),M) \oplus {\rm Ext}(G/[G,G], M)$), but there may be other ways doing it.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have somewhat encountered projective representation and Schur multiplier but haven't solved many problems, so I do not have much understanding. But, feel free to give a solution using these notions.